CreateProcess throws error "The filename or extension is too long"
How to execute a BAT file that is in a folder beyond 300 characters in length? The parameter to CreateProcess throws the error:

The filename or extension is too long

I successfully manage long file names elsewhere with \\?\. I am using Delphi Alexandria.

I'm pretty sure you try to launch cmd.exe and that one is complaining. Why not at least adding the code you use?

How about doing a CHDIR to the directory containing the .BAT file before executing it, so you don't need to specify the path on the command line?

Documentation for CreateProcessW states:

To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set
lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following
arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.
[in, out, optional] lpCommandLine
The command line to be executed.
The maximum length of this string is 32,767 characters, including the
Unicode terminating null character. If lpApplicationName is NULL, the
module name portion of lpCommandLine is limited to MAX_PATH
characters.

So I'm guessing you have your application name set to NULL and then simply pass the filename of your batch file as lcCommandLine parameter which is then limiting you to MAX_PATH length.

Unless you find something better, some ugly way to solve it could be to first create a Symbolic Link called for example 'a' to the large named folder. Something like this:
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "c:\a" -Target "c:\VeryVeryVeryLoooongPaaaathhhh"

So then instead of calling the bat using the original path:
c:\VeryVeryVeryLoooongPaaaathhhh\logic.bat

you can call:
c:\a\logic.bat

Depending on what you are doing, you should then remove the symbolic link, and/or control wether it is already created.
(I haven't tested the syntaxis, so some minor adjustments might be necesary).

Something better is to use the 8.3 names of each folder of a path using GetShortPathNameW(). Your solution relies on PowerShell, which is, again, starting a process (instead of doing it in the program).
